# DB2 Distinct Count

Tags: db2, row-number, db2-400, db2-luw, dense-rank

How to `Count(Distinct ID)` where the Value is equal 1; possibly  using
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... )` ?

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884)

Answer (score 1):

From the data you have supplied, we are able to deduce that you need to determine the count of distinct ID for each **GROUP** and **YRMO** where VALUE = 1 and designate it as a distinct count.

The `COUNT(CASE WHEN condition THEN column END)` syntax allows us to calculate the number of rows that match a condition :

```
SELECT GRP, YRMO, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN val = 1 THEN id END) AS distinct_counts, 
                  COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS total_counts
FROM mytable
GROUP BY GRP, YRMO
```